# Why does the Fairy Tail anime have no blood?

Tags: fairy-tail

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

*Dragon Ball*, *One Piece*, *Bleach*, and *Naruto* all have blood. Why doesn't *Fairy Tail* have it?

Comment: A similar question "Why did they draw clothes on Lisanna, Erza and Natsu in the latest episode (S02E64)?", will probably have the same answer. They censor that stuff to keep the audience as broad as possible to maximize profit. Having blood or nudity will not make the anime appropriate for children.

Comment: Could you add scenes of the other mangas, showing blood? Because I believe they censor a lot of stuff too.

Comment: @PeterRaeves Bleach: http://images2.fanpop.com/image/photos/13900000/Fav-pages-bleach-manga-and-tv-13977537-750-1078.jpg      Naruto:https://mynarutoblog.files.wordpress.com/2010/01/16-1711.png

Comment: All i know is that the movie phoenix priestess has a liiiitle blood thats all i want another fairy tail movie though

Answer (score 11):

The reason for this is **censorship**. Fairy Tail has a 'PG-13' age rating; most shows with this rating do not show gore.

Another example of something they censored would be that in the manga, [Gray Fullbuster](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Gray_Fullbuster) is a smoker. They took this out in the anime because they were afraid it might influence children to think that smoking is cool.

This can be seen in **Chapter 4, Page 20** and **Chapter 10, Page 6-7**.

[image: Gray Fullbuster smoking.]

*On a side note, the first OVA ("Welcome To Fairy Hills!") is the only episode I know of that shows blood before Fairy Tail 2014.*

> [image: Levy after Erza smashed her face into the wall.]
>
>  Levy after Erza smashed her face into the wall (10:05).

Comment: Does the new Fairy Tail,that aired last year,have blood?

Comment: @Daniel not much but definitely some, http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20140405035128/fairytail/images/f/f2/Sting_attacks_Jiemma.png

Comment: Is that not tomato juice? What makes you say it's blood? Also please specify in which chapter Gray is shown smoking? I recall none except the older generation of Fairy Tail member (Macao, Wakaba) smoking.

Comment: @SakuraiTomoko take a look at the first OVA, at 10:05. Erza smashes her face into the wall. Very unlikely for that to be tomato juice...

Comment: @SakuraiTomoko Edited, chapter and page provided in answer :)

Comment: In what system does Fairy Tail have a "T" rating? Neither MPAA nor TVPG have a rating of "T", and I can't imagine that an anime would use ESRB ratings.